# getting integer values from NSMutableArray using objectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an NSMutableArray called george. It has NSInteger values inside: 12, 23, 54, 34, 45.
Now I have a string called unitID its made of a letter and a number eg. t00, e01, t02, e03, t04

what I'm doing is:

```
-(int)getSpawnAmount:(NSString *)unitID
{
typeString = [unitID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
numberString = [unitID substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,2)];


    return [[george objectAtIndex:[numberString integerValue]] integerValue];
}
```

I know that objectAtIndex returns an "id" and im not sure whether im doing it the right way to get the integer values.

Anyway my question is how do I get NSInteger values from my NSMutableArray using objectAtIndex?

Thanks in advance.

My array was in another class and instead of referencing it I was creating a new NSMutableArray, which was blank. My code works fine now. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You are already getting them. What's not working?

Comment: And I suspect that the array(george) does not contain **NSInteger** values. Those should be **NSNumber** s or something.

Comment: It seems like your code is right, but show the code that constructed the array and/or inserted values into it so we can be sure.

Comment: My array was in another class and instead of referencing it I was creating a new NSMutableArray, which was blank. My code works fine now. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The safe way could be to use reflection on type id; so you will be able to put some errorhandling inside.
Otherwise you could cast type id to a NSNumber and so to "any" other type, e.g. int.

Comment: Hi Thomas, can you please tell me what do you mean by reflection on type id and how can i do it.